# onLoad event in React not behaving as I would expect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have the following component:

```
const testLog = () => {   
    console.log('aaa - test') ;
}

const MyComponent = () => (
    <img onLoad={() => testLog()} />    
);
```

I then reference the component in my main app:

```
<MyComponent />
```

I can see that the component definitely appears on the screen - I can see the image component, however, the issue I have is that the log message never fires.

At first, I thought I'd maybe need to bind it, so tried this:

```
const MyComponent = () => (
    <img onLoad={() => this.testLog.bind(this)} />    
);
```

But it then just tells me that `testLog` is not used.

Comment: You need a "src" attribute to your image. Add some image url to it. For example: `<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500" onLoad={() => testLog()} />`

Comment: Oh wow - hadn't realised it never fired load - although I suppose it makes sense that it wouldn't fire load if there's nothing to load.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'd agree with that.  Obviously, that's predicated on the fact that you realise that's a feature of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `onLoad` to fire. You need the img to have src.
Looking at the code you provided, the img tag has nothing to load.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use useEffect hook, please
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
useEffect(()=>{
  // TODO: your code here
  this.testLog.bind(this)
},[]);
```

Comment: There is no need of `this` and `bind` in functional components. That is the point of having functional components and hooks